# Mongoose post Query Middleware hook trigger twice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose [Model.findOneAndupdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) to find and update my document and there is a `post` hook on my model schema for which i'm trying to update another document.

The issue i'm facing is `post` hook is being triggered twice.

My model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const componentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  component: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  message: {
    type: String
  },
  bodyJson: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
  },
  question: {
    type: String
  }
})


componentSchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function (result) {
  console.log('came here')
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Component', componentSchema)
```

In my server log i see that `came here` logged is twice.

update:

```
try {
  await Component.findOneAndUpdate(query, req.body, { new: true }, function (error, doc) {
    if (doc) {
      return res.status(200).json({ data: doc })
    } else if (error) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: error.message })
    } else res.status(404).json({ errors: 'Not found' })
  })
} catch (error) {
  logger.error('error while updating order: ' + error)
  return res.status(400).json({ errors: error.message })
}
```

moongoose version i'm using is 5.8.11

Comment: Can you add the code where you use findOneAndUpdate?

Comment: i update my question now and the weird thing is when i remove the callback in `findOneAndUpdate` it's working fine.

Comment: Uday because you are both using await and callback, only one of them must be used. The fastest fix is just remove await.

Comment: yes it worked thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using both await and callback at the same time. This causes the middleware trigger 2 times. Only one of them must be used.

Use either callback:

```js
Component.findOneAndUpdate(query, req.body, { new: true }, function(
  error,
  doc
) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: error.message }); //500 status code may be better
  } else {
    if (doc) {
      return res.status(200).json({ data: doc });
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ errors: "Not found" });
    }
  }
});
```

Or await:

```js
try {
  const doc = await Component.findOneAndUpdate(query, req.body, { new: true });

  if (doc) {
    return res.status(200).json({ data: doc });
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({ errors: "Not found" });
  }
} catch (error) {
  logger.error("error while updating order: " + error);
  return res.status(400).json({ errors: error.message });
}
```